# How to clear a jQuery-UI dialog which include .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, load

I have a jquery-ui which uses a .load(); function to retrieve it's content, and I need to include two .js file in order to make my dialog work.
Everything is going fine, but if I close the dialog with the cancel button and reopen it, it will keep my .js include and so it will load twice.

Here my HTML file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/commun.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/altimit.js"></script>
<section style="text-align: center;">
    <a id="ajouterArticle">Ajouter un article</a>
</section>

<div id="ajouterArticle" title="Ajouter un article"></div>
```

And my .js :

```
$("a#ajouterArticle").button(); 
$("body").on('click', 'a#ajouterArticle', function() {
    $.post("includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php", { 
        creerArticle: 1
    },
    function(result) {
        $("div#ajouterArticle").hide().html(result).dialog("open");
    }
    );
});

$("div#ajouterArticle").dialog( {
    autoOpen: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    modal: true,
    buttons: [ 
        { 
            text: "Enregistrer",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-disk" },
            click: function() {
                $.post("includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php", 
                    { 
                        id: $('#id').val(),
                        titre: $('#titre').val(),
                        url: $('#url').val(),
                        contenu: $('#contenu').val(),
                        tags: $('#tags').val(),
                        ajouterArticle: 1
                    },
                    function(result) {
                        if(result == 0) {
                            $("form#ajouterArticle").trigger("reset");
                            $("div#ajouterArticle").dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                );
            },
        },
        {
            text: "Annuler",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash" },
            click: function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
             },
        } 
    ]
});
```

Here is my php code:

```
function creerArticle() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/commun.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/altimit.js"></script>';
        echo '<form id="ajouterArticle" method="post">';
            echo '<fieldset>';
            echo '<p align="center">';
                echo '<label for="titre">Titre</label><br />';
                echo '<input type="text" name="titre" id="titre" placeholder="Titre" size="50" required>';
            echo '</p>';
            echo '<p align="center">';
                echo '<label for="url">Adresse</label><br />';
                echo '<input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Adresse" size="100" required>';
            echo '</p>';
            echo '<p align="center">';
                echo '<label for="contenu">Contenu</label><br />';
                include("../core/bbcode.inc.php");
                echo '<textarea name="contenu" id="contenu" placeholder="Contenu" cols="120" rows="20" required></textarea>';
            echo '</p>';
            echo '<p align="center">';
                echo '<label for="tags">Tags</label><br />';
                echo '<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="Tags" size="75">';
            echo '</p>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="create">';
            echo '</fieldset>';
        echo '</form>';

}
```

When I first open the dialog, Firebug shows:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php 200 OK 2ms
GET http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/js/commun.js?_=1389180441681 200 OK 1ms    
GET http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/js/altimit.js?_=1389180441682 200 OK 1ms
```

If I click on "Cancel" ("Annuler" in my code, and then reopen the dialog, Firebug shows:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php 200 OK 15ms 
POST http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/ajax/altimit.ajax.php 200 OK 2ms  
GET http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/js/commun.js?_=1389180441683 200 OK 1ms    
GET http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/js/commun.js?_=1389180441684 200 OK 1ms    
GET http://localhost:8888/Whirlwind/altimit/includes/js/altimit.js?_=1389180441685 200 OK 3ms
```

So my .js file are load twice and i don't know how to avoid that.

I have searched on Internet for more than 7 hours and try many things with `.remove();`, `.destroy('dialog');`, and others things. But with this, my dialog can not be reopened and that's not what I want.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The `commun.js` and `altimit.js` is already included in your page so why don't you just simply remove the reference to these two files from your AJAX code?

Comment: Because when you use .load(); function, it do not load the script. So i need to load it inside the .load(). It's very annoying...

Comment: But when the _HTML file_ loads it also loads the two scripts. So why do you want to load them again?

Comment: In this two .js file, i have some js i use in the dialog. But when my load(); is complete, there is no script inside it. I need to recall them for using it in the dialog :/

Comment: @Koshinin -- try adding the js that you need to execute on dialog DOM loaded in a function  and call that function in php file that is  your ajax file.Then u can remove the script tag for the php file.

Comment: I don't know how to manage it. (I'm not very good with js function). But in every case, i should use a <script> tag inside my dialog in order to have my code run ?